# remove com port using devcon (for loop)

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt, devcon

I was trying to delete com port using command line. Right now I am using devcon.exe that is a part of windows WDK. I have tried using devcon findall =ports and used devcon remove "@some specific id". It worked totally well.

Instead of removing them one by one, I wanna write a for loop to remove all of them. I tried this in a batch file:

```
for /f %%i in ('devcon findall %*1*') do (devcon remove "@%%i")
```

It runs but does not have any effect. Anyone knows how to fix it?